# Bibtex. How can I input the term "to appear in" between the journal title and publisher name

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran, ieee-style

I am using the document class as

```
\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran} % 2 column
```

and

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,draftcls,12pt]{IEEEtran} % 1 column
```

In addition, I am compile my tex files with "myBibList.bib" using the following codes.

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,myBibList}
```

---

With above codes, I want to put a reference as follows:

> A. Tom, B. Michael, and C. Johnson, "Journal title," to appear in *IEEE Trans. Wireless Commun*.

I am using the following environments: @article{ ... }

ps) For a journal that will be published soon (already accepted) in IEEE TWC, is it fine if I write it as `A. Tom, B. Michael, and C. Johnson, "Journal title," to appear in *IEEE Trans. Wireless Commun*`.

Comment: Have you considered placing `forthcoming` in the entry's `year` field?

Comment: I would rather write "accepted for publication in" to make it clear that it is not simply submitted, but already accepted.

Comment: @DavideM - In my academic field (economics) and in all other fields I'm familiar with, "forthcoming" -- when used with the `@article` entry type and a non-empty `journal` field -- is very much a synonym for "accepted for publication". What field are you in to make you think that "forthcoming" is a synonym for "submitted to"?

Comment: @Mico I am working in the electronics engineering field and basically all I read comes from IEEE publications. Apart from this, I realise just now that my comment appears to refer to yours, while I meant to compare Danny_Kim's "to appear in" with my "accepted for publication in"; my bad this was not clear. As a non-English mothertongue, I would find "forthcoming" ambiguous as to whether it is just submitted or already accepted, but I acknowledge this is at least subjective, if not simply incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. But what I'm really curious about is how to code in bibtex.